# Entity Framework Automapper pagination IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, pagination, automapper

I have a two entities, `AppUser` and `InterestTag`:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<InterestTag> InterestTags { get; set; }
}

public class InterestTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

They are configured in the `DataContext` with a direct many to many relationship

```
builder.Entity<AppUser>()
        .HasMany(u => u.InterestTags)
        .WithMany(ut => ut.AppUsers);
```

I'm trying to make a method that gets all the `InterestTags` of a user by the user's username, then projects the `InterestTag` to a `InterestTagDto` and paginates the results.

The `InterestTagDto`:

```
public class InterestTagDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping is configured as

```
CreateMap<InterestTag, InterestTagDto>();
```

The `PagedList` class:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = count;
        AddRange(items);
    }

    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
}
```

The method I have so far:

```
    public async Task<PagedList<InterestTagDto>> GetUserInterestTagsAsync(string username)
    {
        var query = (await _context.Users.Include(u => u.InterestTags).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == username)).InterestTags.AsQueryable();

        return await PagedList<InterestTagDto>.CreateAsync(query.ProjectTo<InterestTagDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .AsNoTracking(), 1, 20);
    }
```

On the line

```
var count = await source.CountAsync();
```

of `PagedList<>`, I get an error

> The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations

I think the problem is that after it's mapped to the DTO it's type is a HashSet:

```
{System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[API.Entities.InterestTag].Select(dtoInterestTag => new InterestTagDto() {Id = dtoInterestTag.Id, Name = dtoInterestTag.Name})}
```

I have a similar function that works which gets a list of `AppUsers` and maps it to a `MemberDto` and uses the same `PagedList` class.

After mapping the type is:

```
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<API.DTOs.MemberDto>}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your "query" (which is actually not a query but a materialized query result):

```cs
var query = (await _context.Users.Include(u => u.InterestTags).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == username)).InterestTags.AsQueryable();
```

You are materializing your query with `SingleOrDefaultAsync` so EF will call the database and map the data to memory using .NET classes and collections making `AppUser.InterestTags` some collection and build in collections usually do not implement `IAsyncQueryProvider` which leads to the error you are facing.

There are several possible workaround:

1. Create  `PagedList.CreateAsync` overload which accepts `IEnumerable` and pass it your query result as ordinary enumerable, not queryable.
2. Rewrite query so it is actually a query. Something like this:

```cs
var query = await _context.Users
     .Where(u => u.UserName == username)) // assuming UserName is unique
     .SelectMany(t => t.InterestTags);
// pass to CreateAsync ...
```

P.S.

Also in general try to prevent overfetching (you need only `InterestTags` but fetch from the database the rest of user data from `User` table, though it will not lead to the provided error).